# Using a global JS Object as the state for a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We're building a simulation tool and we are trying to replace our current implementation of how our popups are handled using React.

The issue is that the state of our popup component is set to

```
this.state = connections[this.props.id]
```

that object is a global object that exists, gets created and update in a separate js file and if I go into the console and change connections[this.props.id].name from "junction 15" to "junction 12", the changes are not rendered immediately. I have to close and reopen the popup so it renders with the correct information.

This is something our architect wants, and the way he explained it was that he needs any changes made to our connections object outside of react NEED to reflected within our popup if it's open, but if the state is set to the marker and I modify the name of the marker in the object through the console, i dont understand why it's not automatically being updated in React

I've looked at trying to use the lifecycle methods, redux, mobx, js proxies, react context but I'm still learning and I think I'm making this more complicated than it should be.

Here's our simple popup with components:

```
let globalValue = 'initial'

class ReactButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = connections[this.props.id];
        this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
    }
    updateOutsideReactMade() {
    this.setState(state);
    // this.forceUpdate();
}
    changeName(newName) {
        connections[this.props.id].name = newName;
        this.setState(connections[this.props.id]);
    }

    // ignore this, this was my attempt at using a lifecycle method
    //componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
    //    if (this.props.name !== prevProps.name) {
    //        this.setState(this.props.name);
    //    }
    //}

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Input onChange={this.changeName} />
                <Header name={this.state.name}
                        id={this.state.id}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function renderReactButton(iddd, type){
    ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactButton id={iddd} />,
    document.getElementById(`react-component-${type}-${iddd}`)
    );
}




   class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.name}
                {this.props.id}</h1>
        );
    }
}


class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }


    handleChange(e) {
        const name = e.target.value;
        this.props.onChange(name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        );
    }
}
```

So my question is how am i able to use an object (connections) that is global as my state for react AND if something modifies the data outside of React that it would be reflected on DOM. Right now, we have it working to where we can change the name through the react popups, but if we change the name through the console it will not update. Thank you guys!

****UPDATE**** 8/15/18
I wrapped each new object as a proxy as it was entered in my array.

```
connections[key] = new Proxy(polyLine, handleUpdatesMadeToMarkersOutsideOfReact);
```

I setup a handler:

```
let handleUpdatesMadeToMarkersOutsideOfReact = {
    get: (connections, id) => {

        return connections[id];
    },

    set: (connections, id, value) => {
        //trigger react re-render
        console.log('inside set');

        //trigger react to update

        return true;
    }

};
```

Now I'm stuck trying to get the handler to trigger my react component to update. I created a class function for my component that forced the update but I was having a hard time accessing it with the way we have it setup.

Comment: React updates the UI when you do `setState`, if you modify the state without calling setState, the UI won't update unless you call forceUpdate manually.  Saying all this, for React I use proxy's to manage state, and this is so much easier.

Comment: Hey man, I added  some code above can you help me try to get the update to get triggered in my react componenet?

Answer (score 0):

Normally `state` is an object - giving existing object is ok. React requires `setState` usage to be able to process lifecycle, f.e. render with updated state. Modyfying state object from console doesn't let react to react ;)

You need some kind of observer, sth to tell react than data changed and to force render (call `this.forceUpdate()`).

Comment: Ill give that a try, ty!